# SP.SOD.loadMultiple Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, project-server

I am trying to load the project context in order to access some data. 
I am using the SP.SOD.loadMultiple function as follows:

```
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['sp.core.js', 'sp.runtime.js', 'sp.js', 'ps.js'], DoSomething());

function DoSomething() { alert('x'); }
```

If I remove `'ps.js'` everyting works fine, but I won't be able to access project context.

I've checked and the file exists in the server: `server_address/PWA/_layouts/15/ps.js`

Someone knows what may be the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function `LoadMultiple` has the following signature:

```
function LoadMultipleSods(keys, fn, bSync)
```

where the first argument accepts the array of SOD keys, `RegisterSod` function is used for registering JS function.

Most probably in your case the registration of `ps.js` library is missing. In order to load `ps.js` library it has to be registered *first* and then could be loaded as demonstrated below:

```
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
SP.SOD.registerSod('PS.ProjectContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('ps.js'));
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'PS.ProjectContext'], function(){

   console.log('sp.js has been loaded..');
   console.log('ps.js has been loaded..');

});
```